# Division sum "DS" of a number

Tags: calculus, limits

Let S be the sum of digits of a natural number $n$. Let $DS$ the function defined by $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, DS(n)=\frac{S\left(n^2\right)}{S(n)}$$

Now let $$A=\{DS(n)|n \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$$

I want to prove that $$\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}A=0$$

But I have no idea how, do you have any ideas?

**NB :**
With my computer and a small string of python code I have found this distribution for $0\le n \le 1000$ 
[image]

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What makes you think the infimum should be $0$? You would have to occasionally have a lot more non-zero digits in $n$ (and I mean, a lot more, i.e. increasingly more for certain $n$ as $n$ increases) compared to $n^2$ in order for this to be true. But the obvious connection between 0 digits in $n$ and $n^2$ is that if you have a lot in $n$, and $n$ is of the right form (e.g. $n = 10^k$) then you will have a lot in $n^2$. But even then if $n = 10^k$ the ratio of the sum of digits would be 1.

Comment: I don't know but I think its true. For example there is no zero in 489899 and its DS is 0.27 so maybe your argument is not totally true?

Comment: @Shaddock Don't get me wrong, I'm not claiming that anything is true. =) I'm just saying, since $n^2$ has twice as many digits, it would be surprising if you could get the ratio to go to $0$. And if it is true, it might be pretty hard to prove, as your example of $489899$ indicates.

Comment: If it is true, I think your best bet is to look at squared numbers of the form $n^2 = 10^k + m$ where $k$ is odd and $m$ is either very small or doesn't have too many non-zero digits. You should get a corresponding $n$ that begins with a $3$ and (hopefully) has lots of non-zero digits. This is also something you could try in your simulation.

Comment: This has been recently asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709020)