# Proof of $\inf\left \{ \frac{\mathrm{d} (n^2)}{\mathrm{d} (n)} \; \bigg| \; n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}=0$, where $d(n)$ is the sum of digits of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, supremum-and-infimum, decimal-expansion

So I wanted to find the infimum of the set described in the title, and I'm pretty confident on what the subsequence should be to ensure a 0 infimum.

> $[4899,4899899999,4899899999899999999999, \dotsc]$, where the next term in the sequence is the previous + '8' + '9' * $(2s+1)$, where $s$ is the length of the previous set of consecutive nines. In the sequence I provided, it goes 2,5,11... (I'm fairly confident 1,3,7,15... also works).

But a proof of this eludes me. I tried some funky stuff with the multinomial theorem and binomial theorem

> $(10^6 4899 + 899999)^2$ and tried to chunk it based on the first section and second but I really couldn't go anywhere due to the $2\cdot 899999 \cdot 10^6 \cdot 4899$ term.

EDIT: 49 is a good starting term to look at.

Comment: so, why do you think the infimum is zero?

Comment: @WillJagy the sequence in spoiler approaches 0 the further you go along, I tested i think the 10th term? and it was 0.004 (the ratio).

Comment: What is the question here? Are you asking how to prove the infimum is zero? Or are you asking if your sequence specifically proves this? For the first there is a sequence of numbers that does prove the claim.

Comment: @Sil I want to prove that my sequence (or any other one) does achieve an infimum of 0, which I think is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is true. Here is a solution based on [this AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h298035p1614225). Let

$$
n=10^{4k}+2\cdot10^{3k}-10^{2k}+2\cdot10^{k}+1.
$$

Then you can check that
$$
n=10^{4k}+10^{3k}+9\cdot 10^{3k-1}+9\cdot 10^{3k-2}+\dots+9\cdot 10^{2k}+2\cdot 10^k+1\\
n^2=10^{8k}+4\cdot 10^{7k}+2\cdot 10^{6k}+10^{4k+1}+10^{4k}+2\cdot 10^{2k}+4\cdot 10^{k}+1.
$$

Thus
$$
\frac{d(n^2)}{d(n)}=\frac{1+4+2+1+1+2+4+1}{1+1+9k+2+1}=\frac{16}{9k+5} \to 0 \text { as } k\to \infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the letters $j$  and $n$  as shown below, it comes out
$$ d(n) = 9 \cdot 2^j - j - 4  $$

$$ d(n^2) = j^2 - j +7  $$

Getting there. I see, let us say, the ingredients of a proof allowing an explicit description. Let us call a number $\theta$  in base ten with  most digits $0$   but, reading left to right, at positions $1, 3, 7, ..., 2^j - 1.$  That is, $$  \theta =  10^{2^j - 2}  + 10^{2^j - 4} + 10^{2^j - 8} + ...  +  10^{2^{j-1} } + 1 $$

Compare this brief printout

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
Tue 30 May 2023 12:14:39 PM PDT
4899    3     30       9     24000201
 101  theta 
 10201  theta^2 

Tue 30 May 2023 12:14:39 PM PDT
48989999    5     65       13     2400020002020001
 1010001  theta 
 1020102020001  theta^2 

Tue 30 May 2023 12:14:39 PM PDT
4898999899999999    7     136       19     24000200020200000202000200000001
 101000100000001  theta 
 10201020200010202000200000001  theta^2 

Tue 30 May 2023 12:14:39 PM PDT
48989998999999989999999999999999    10     279       27     2400020002020000020200020000000002020002000000020000000000000001
 1010001000000010000000000000001  theta 
 1020102020001020200020000000102020002000000020000000000000001  theta^2 

Tue 30 May 2023 12:14:39 PM PDT
4898999899999998999999999999999899999999999999999999999999999999    15     566       37     24000200020200000202000200000000020200020000000200000000000000000202000200000002000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000001
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

repeat

$$  \theta =  10^{2^j - 2}  + 10^{2^j - 4} + 10^{2^j - 8} + ...  +  10^{2^{j-1} } + 1 $$

Then the numbers $n$  that optimize your ratio   are
$$ n = \frac{1}{2}   10^{2^j} - \theta   $$
so that

$$ n^2 = \frac{1}{4}   10^{2^{j+1}} -  10^{2^j}\theta + \theta^2  $$

and we can calculate this. It is the top digit of $10^{2^j}\theta$  that provides the decrease from $2.5$ down to $2.4$

with summation signs   $ \theta = \sum_{k=1}^j 10^{2^j - 2^k} $   for
$$ \theta = 10^{2^j - 2} + \sum_{k=2}^j 10^{2^j - 2^k} $$
so
$$ 10^{2^j} \theta = 10^{2^{j+1} - 2} + \sum_{k=2}^j 10^{2^{j+1} - 2^k} $$

Next
$$     \frac{1}{4}   10^{2^{j+1}}  = 25 \cdot    10^{2^{j+1} - 2}          $$

and
$$   n^2 =  24 \cdot    10^{2^{j+1} - 2}  + \theta^2 -  \sum_{k=2}^j 10^{2^{j+1} - 2^k} $$

Time to expand $\theta^2$ carefully.........